# wso2 product configuration & testing setup guide

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am novice to WSO2 platform.

We are in the process of evaluating WSO2 product suite for integration requirement with SAP via SAPJco.

After going through product documentation, I got to know that I would be using below products in WSO2

1. Carbon server (as this is base) - Ant Configuration, Apache Ant,
   Maven
2. ESB (Data transformation)
3. Message Broker (for asynchronous communication) - In turn this needs
   Active MQ & JMS
4. Developer studio (for developing mediation flow & for deploying run
   time component)

I would be working on a POC for the above case study & would require quick start guide or a reference document to configure & setup my environment since there are four different products & would need to bring all under single umbrella.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sample at [1], little closely assemble you requirement. You can refer the documentation for each product at WSO2 website, for ESB it's [2]. You can find the documentation for other products in the same place.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Retail+Banking+Sample

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Getting+Started

Thanks,
Pushpalanka